# XAML - Fix controls' position in a wrappanel

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, user-interface

I have a wrap panel which contains number of controls(as below) and depends on the scenario those controls might show/hide except 2 controls which will always show and need to be in the fixed position in the wrappanel.

---

DynamicControl1     DynamicControl2     DynamicControl3     **FixedControl1     FixedControl2**

DynamicControl4     DynamicControl5     DynamicControl6     DynamicControl7     DynamicControl8

---

What I want to achieve is: If DynamicControl3 and DynamicControl4 collapsed, the subsequent dynamic controls needs to automatically take the empty spaces as below:

---

DynamicControl1     DynamicControl2     DynamicControl5     **FixedControl1     FixedControl2**

DynamicControl6     DynamicControl7     DynamicControl8

---

but by the default behavior of wrap panel, the FixedControl1 and FixedControl2 will take that empty spaces which is what I don't want.

Comment: not clear what are you asking for..

Comment: Just updated the question, hope this will make the question more clear

Comment: One solution to your problem can be to write your own panel. That's not really complicated for your scenario.

Are the other controls fixed in size? Or can DC1,DC2,D3 be wider in combination than DC1,DC2,DC5?

I am asking because you could sort the children of the panel. This does of course not work if theres only one control before the fixed ones f.e.

Comment: All controls can have different width, so if empty space is not enough to fit in the subsequent control, I would like to leave the empty space there.

Comment: @json your controls are of same type? you are creating these controls statically in xaml?

Comment: @nit They are different types and Yes, I've created them statically in xaml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between the hidden and collapsed visibility. Try to set the DynamicControls to Visibility.Hidden. Then they still consume their space and take their position. Is that possible in your case?

--- EDIT ----

I believe you can only write your own panel. That's actually easy. Just override the two methods MeasureOverride and ArrangeOverride. All you need to do is arrange the fixed controls first (mark them with an attached property) and den put the others controls around them. One by one from left to right until the remaining size (Viewport - Size of the fixed controls (incl. margins) is less than the row of dynamic controls. Then just move to the next line (y offset + height of largest control in upper line).

Not to complicated. :)

Comment: Unfortunately no. In that case the subsequent controls will not able to show in first row automatically, that's why I'm using Wrap Panel.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you're trying to explain. Is it so dynamic that there will be different controls before the fixed ones?

Comment: BTW. your text is very unclear. You are talking about DynamicControl4 two times and usually the WrapPanel runs from left to right, but in your case it appears to be different.

Comment: Yes, all the controls are dynamic except 2 fixed controls which needs to be show in the end of first row. so DynamicContro1 and DynamicContro2 can be hidden also, and if they are hidden the DynamicContro3 and DynamicContro4 need to be displayed in the 1st and 2nd position in first row

Comment: sorry for the confusion, Just updated the question hope this will make the question more clear